# Discord.js Can't Check 'lastMessage.content'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
function broadcast() {
  client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {
    g.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'chat' && c.lastMessage.content !== 'test').send('test')
    })
};

setInterval(broadcast, 3000);
```

This code doesn't work. If you don't understand, I'm trying to get all channels named 'chat' and by the way the last message is not the broadcast message, then send a message to the channel.

```
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715482+00:00 app[worker.1]:  
    c.lastMessage.content !== 'test'
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715483+00:00 app[worker.1]:                           ^
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715483+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715484+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715484+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/events/ready.js:22:27
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715485+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Map.find (/app/node_modules/@discordjs/collection/dist/index.js:160:17)
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715486+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/events/ready.js:20:28
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715486+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715486+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Timeout.broadcast [as _onTimeout] (/app/events/ready.js:19:29)
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715487+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
2020-07-09T13:33:43.715487+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

This is the error that I get.

Comment: Can you share the result of a `console.log(client.guilds.cache)` placed in the very beginning of `broadcast` function? Apparently, the data you receive is not exactly as you expect

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
function broadcast() {
  client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {
    const channel = g.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'chat')
    if (channel.lastMessage.content !== 'test') channel.send('test')
  })
};

setInterval(broadcast, 3000);
```

Comment: It didn't, it says
    2020-07-10T11:29:15.610164+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null

Comment: Looks like situation is about the lastMessage object

Answer (score 0):

It may occur that there is no last message in a channel, resulting in `c.lastMessage` being `undefined`, and making your process close when trying to reach a non-existent `content` key.
In order to prevent this, you could test for this instead :

````js
g.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'chat' && (c.lastMessage && c.lastMessage.content !== 'test'))
```
````

Comment: it's also not working, I believe I'm using 'lastMessage' object wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so (It took me 5/10 minutes) i got it

```js
msg = 'Your message'

function broadcast() {
// Check all servers
  client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {
// then all channels
    g.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'chat').forEach(c =>{
// if the last message on the channel is not not your message, it will send it
if(c.messages.cache.first().content !=== msg) c.send('test'):
    })
  })
};
// Interval you asked for
setInterval(broadcast, 3000);
```